# \section does not go to the right place

Tags: sectioning, figure-placement

I would like to insert 4 images one after the other (each filling 1 page) and then make a tcolorbox and then a new \section{}.
Since the 1st image does not completely fill the first A4 page, the tcolorbox and the \section{} are displayed at the end of the first page instead of at the end of the 4 pages.

How can I change this?

```
\input{settings/settings-Skript-German}



\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[R]{\small Rationale Zahlen} %Kopfzeile links
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} %obere Trennlinie
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} %untere Trennlinie

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}

%\changefont{cmss}{m}{n}
%\thispagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{LARGE}
\textbf{Rationale Zahlen}\\
\end{LARGE}

\thispagestyle{empty}

Rationale Zahlen nennen wir alle Zahlen, die als Verhältnis zweier ganzen Zahlen
dargestellt werden können. Die Menge aller rationalen Zahlen nennen wir $\mathbb{Q}$ (von
„Quotient“). Sie umfasst alle Zahlen, die sich als Bruch darstellen lassen, der sowohl im Zähler als auch im Nenner ganze Zahlen enthält. Formal sieht das so aus:

\begin{equation*}
    \mathbb{Q} = \{\frac{p}{q} \phantom{a} | \phantom{d} p \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ und } q \in \mathbb{Z}\}
\end{equation*}
Mit diesem Dossier kannst du das Thema Rationale Zahlen selbständig erarbeiten. Du wirst lernen:
\begin{itemize}
    \item wozu man Brüche braucht
    \item wie man Brüche kürzt und erweitert
    \item wie man mit Brüchen rechnet: Addition, Subtraktion, Multiplikation und Division
    \item wie man mit Doppel- und Mehrfachbrüchen umgeht
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Vorgehen:}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Lies dir die Erklärungen im Theorieteil genau durch und studiere die Illustrationen. Streiche an, was dir besonders wichtig erscheint.
    \item Löse die angegebenen Aufgaben aus dem Schulbuch Arithmetik \& Algebra und korrigiere dich selbständig mit den Lösungen.
    \item Löse nach jedem Abschnitt die Lernkontrolle und zeige deine Lösungen deiner Lehrperson. Fahre erst mit dem nächsten Abschnitt weiter, wenn deine Lehrerperson dir das OK dafür gibt.
\end{itemize}

Quelle der Theorieteile:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Lambacher Schweizer 7/8, Klett und Balmer AG, Zug, 2011.
    \item Algebra 7/8, Orell Füssli Verlag, Zürich, 2019.
    
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{pics/1.png}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{pics/2.png}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{pics/3.png}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{pics/4.png}
\end{figure}

\newpage
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \textbf{Aufgaben:} Löse in dein Übungsheft (Titel nicht vergessen!) und korrigiere selbständig.\\
    A \& A, S. 52 - 55: 1, 3, 5, 9, 13, 15, 17, 23, 25, 29, 33, 35, 37, 41, 45
\end{tcolorbox}
\section*{Lernkontrolle 1: Kürzen und Erweitern von Brüchen}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.8]{pics/LK1.png}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{5.png}
\end{figure}
\newpage
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1.3]{6.png}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \textbf{Aufgaben: Addition und Subtraktion}\\
    Löse in dein Übungsheft und korrigiere selbständig.\\
    A \& A, S. 56 - 57: 51, 55, 57, 59ac, 63, 65, 69, 71, 75
\end{tcolorbox}
```

The input file has the following content:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
%\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, landscape]{article}
%\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

%\usepackage[top=2.6cm,bottom=2.8cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, headheight=15pt, headsep = 0.5cm, footskip = 0.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=15mm, right=15mm, bottom=25mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm} 
%\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{a4paper, top=30mm, left=27mm, right=26mm, bottom=30mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm} 
%\newgeometry{a4paper, top=20mm, left=15mm, right=15mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=5mm, footskip=12mm} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %wählt die richtige Schriftkodierung. In unserem Fall vor allem wichtig, dass LaTex Wörter mit Umlauten richtig trennen kann.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %damit wir Umlaute direkt ohne Umwege eingeben können
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %ngerman=neue deutsche Rechtschreibung
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pifont} %für spezielle aufzählungspunkte
\usepackage{enumerate} %dadurch kann man Art der Aufzählung hinter enumerate befehl hinschreiben
\usepackage{graphicx} %Grafiken einbinden: jpeg, png
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} %Paragraphen werden nummeriert bis in die 3. Ebene
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} %Paragraphen werden im Inhaltsverzeichnis nummeriert bis 3. Ebene
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath} %Brüche besser darstellen
\usepackage{setspace} %doppelter zeilenabstand
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{polynom} %polynomdivision
\usepackage{ mathrsfs } %geschwungene Buchstaben

\usepackage{amsfonts} %mengen
\usepackage{amssymb} %mengen

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{myColor2}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.7}% Wir definieren im RGB-Farbraum
%\colorbox{myColor}{\parbox{\columnwidth}{}}

\definecolor{myColor}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}% Wir definieren im RGB-Farbraum
%\colorbox{myColor}{\parbox{\columnwidth}{}}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{tabularx}

%\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=20mm, right=20mm, bottom=25mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm} 

\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{bm} %fett 

\usepackage{tikz} %häuschen

\newcommand\kariert[2][0.4cm]{% 
   \begin{tikzpicture}[gray,step=#1]
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro\anzahl{(\linewidth-\pgflinewidth)/#1} % maximale Anzahl Kästchen pro Zeile
     \draw (0,0) rectangle (\anzahl*#1,#2*#1) (0,0) grid (\anzahl*#1,#2*#1);
   \end{tikzpicture} 
}

\newcommand{\liniert}[2][0.4cm]{% 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[gray]
  \path[use as bounding box](0,0)rectangle(\linewidth,-#2*#1-0.5\pgflinewidth); 
   \foreach \n in {1,...,#2}\draw(0 ,-#1*\n )--(\linewidth,-#1*\n ); 
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  
  \newcommand\kariertt[2][1cm]{% 
   \begin{tikzpicture}[gray,step=#1]
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro\anzahl{(\linewidth-\pgflinewidth)/#1} % maximale Anzahl Kästchen pro Zeile
     \draw (0,0) rectangle (\anzahl*#1,#2*#1) (0,0) grid (\anzahl*#1,#2*#1);
   \end{tikzpicture} 
}

\newcommand{\liniertt}[2][1cm]{% 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[gray]
  \path[use as bounding box](0,0)rectangle(\linewidth,-#2*#1-0.5\pgflinewidth); 
   \foreach \n in {1,...,#2}\draw(0 ,-#1*\n )--(\linewidth,-#1*\n ); 
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc} 

\newcommand{\grad}{^{\circ}}
\newcommand{\bild}[2]{{\begin{figure}[h] \centering \includegraphics[width=#2]{#1} \end{figure}}}
\newcommand{\vs}[1]{\vspace{#1 cm}}
\newcommand{\grau}[1]{\colorbox{myColor}{\parbox{\columnwidth}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\haus}[1]{\begin{minipage}{17.8cm}  \kariert{#1} \end{minipage} \vs{0.5}}

%\linewidth

\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\K}{\mathbb{K}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\X}{\mathbb{X}}



\newcommand{\hauss}[1]{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}  \kariertt{#1} \end{minipage} \vs{0.5}}

\newcounter{aufg}
\newcommand{\aufg}{\addtocounter{aufg}{1}
\subsubsection{Aufgabe \theaufg}}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{tabto}

%\usepackage{enumitem}

% Umgebung: Alphabetische, Numerische etc. Aufzählungen
\newenvironment{myenum}[1][\alph]
{
    \begin{enumerate}[label = #1*)]
    }
    {
    \end{enumerate}
}


\newenvironment{myenum2}[1][2]
{
    \vspace{-\topskip}
    \begin{multicols}{#1}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph{*})]%}
        }
        {\end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
    \vspace{-\topskip}
}


\newenvironment{myitem}
{
    \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, leftmargin=1cm]
    }
    {
    \end{itemize}
}


\newenvironment{myitem2}[1][2]
{
    \vspace{-0.5\topskip}
    \begin{multicols}{#1}
        \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, leftmargin=1cm]
        }
        {
        \end{itemize}
    \end{multicols}
    \vspace{-\topskip}
}
```

Comment: we can not check your example, but perhaps change `\newpage` to `\clearpage`. The section does not move, but the only reason to use `figure` is to allow it to move.

Comment: It didnt made a difference...

Comment: floats will float past \newpage but not past \clearpage, other than that it is hard to help as you have not provided any example that shows the issue.

Comment: if your floats each fill a page  you should not use `[h]` as the main effect is to prevent the default `[p]`  that makes a page of floats.

Comment: Maybe not related to the problem, but do you acutally _need_ all those packages? Also, see if you can reproduce the issue using a code with `\rule{wd}{ht}` in place of the `\includegraphics` commands, where `ht` and `wd` are appropriate widths and heights. Then no additional files are needed.

Comment: Your other option (instead of `\rule{wd}{ht}`) is to `\includegraphics{example-image}` and make sure that it shows the problem you claim it shows.  If I do that and change the `\newpage` to `\clearpage`, then I get a page break at the place I think you want.  But it's hard to tell, since you've spread a lot of code that isn't really necessary and has 7 figures, 2 tcolorboxes, and 1 section, when your question only talks about 4, 1, and 1.

Comment: At least one of your packages is unnecessary since it is only used to create examples and your example doesn't use it. In addition to loading only packages you need (in your real document, as well as here), don't load packages twice. But you should probably be using `enumitem`, judging by your custom environments.